# EntityDeploySplit error - Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll missing

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

After a clean Windows reformat and installing Visual Studio 2013, trying to build a project with database-first Entity Framework edmx files yields the following error:

> The "EntityDeploySplit" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll. Could
>   not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll' or one
>   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Is there some way to install this separately?  What is this assembly included with by default?

**UPDATE:** This also manifests itself when looking for the EntityClean task.  I'm inclined to think that it checks the bin first, since another developer who was running it fine tried a clean / rebuild and then this started showing up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this problem and was able to fix it as I have described below. Your paths and variables may be different.

I found that when my project builds it points to this target file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets
```

That target file appears to just be a placeholder. There is an Import element, in that file, that points to `$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets` which runs the target file located at that path. I searched registry and found that `MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath` is a registry entry with the value of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\`

I went to the targets file that was referenced and search for the `UsingTask` element that was specified in my exception. Inside the `UsingTask` element, the `AssemblyFile` attribute was pointed to `$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll`. I searched the registry and found that the MSBuildBinPath registry entry was pointed to `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\`

I'm not sure why it was pointed to that, maybe a Framework or Visual Studio installation didn't clean it up. Finally, **I changed all my `UsingTask` elements' `AssemblyFile` attributes to:**

`$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll`

I used the same variable that was in the MSBuild Bin target file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 14):

I found the accepted answer to be a little confusing, below are the steps that worked for me.

Open C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets in notepad.

Alter the UsingTask elements to:

```
  <UsingTask TaskName="EntityDeploySplit"
             AssemblyFile="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="EntityDeploy"
             AssemblyFile="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="EntityDeploySetLogicalNames"
             AssemblyFile="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll" />

  <UsingTask TaskName="EntityClean"
             AssemblyFile="Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll" />
```

Comment: This was definitely easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

I give a lot of credit to [Andy Mahaffey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22919007/1836630) for his answer, without it I would not have found what I did.
I followed along his line of research but didn't like the idea of just changing the UsingTasks' attributes.  I opened up the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets" file and I found the first thing it says after the opening Project element is this comment:

```
  <!-- This .targets file can be used by updating Microsoft.Common.targets to 
         include the line below (as the last import element just before the end project tag)
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets')"/>
  -->
```

I followed it's suggestion and presto, problems solved.

I hope this helps!

#### TLDR

Paste the line below as the last element before the  tag in the following file. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets')"/>
```

Comment: I tried this one first as well because it seemed less invasive. But it didn't work for me. Following this answer did the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249247/131944

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had accidentally created two copies of one of my .edmx files, one in a subfolder, where I didn't notice it. Once I deleted the extra one, everything was fine.