# msbuild.exe works but msbuild API does not

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I want to automate my builds using MSBuild API, but it gives me an error. I have my automation project in Visual Studio 2015. It references MSBuild v12.0 dlls.

Code I'm using to build a solution:

```
private bool Execute()
{
    var buildProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    buildProperties["Configuration"] = "Debug";
    var solution = @"C:\test\test.sln";
    bool success = Build(solution, buildProperties)
    return success;
}

private bool Build(string solution, Dictionary<string, string> buildProperties)
{
    Guard.ValidPath(solution, nameof(solution));
    BuildParameters buildParam = new BuildParameters()

    BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(solution, buildProperties, null, new string[] { "Build" }, null);
    BuildResult buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParam, buildRequest);
    if (buildResult.OverallResult == BuildResultCode.Success)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

The solution has one project. It's configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
etc.
```

The error I get:

> : ERROR
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Data.Entity.targets(65,5):
>   The "EntityDeploySplit" task could not be instantiated from the
>   assembly
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll".
>   Please verify the task assembly has been built using the same version
>   of the Microsoft.Build.Framework assembly as the one installed on your
>   computer and that your host application is not missing a binding
>   redirect for Microsoft.Build.Framework. Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.EntityDeploySplit' to type
>   'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask'

Any idea how to overcome this error? Why this happens?

Comment: Your question is answered in this [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20400054/entitydeploysplit-error-microsoft-data-entity-build-tasks-dll-missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by referencing Microsoft.Build.Framework v14.0, other Microsoft.Build dlls are v12.0. Now it works!

Comment: Can you post the code changes for referencing the v14.0 Build Framework? I'm trying to build C++ using BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build() and I have a similar error (using vs2015)

Answer (score 5):

Had a similar problem but another error message. My web projects couldn't build because they tried to cast their tasks to Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. I think the problem was that they used an older version and therefore unable to cast to the new version of ITask. Found this solution for MSBuild 3.5 and it works for 14.0 too.

[MSDN Forum: MSBuild crashes with a "Message" task could not be instantiated exception](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/2772a075-4e2f-42af-9e7a-2228b794368e/msbuild-crashes-with-a-message-task-could-not-be-instantiated-exception)

I changed 3.5 to 14.0 and added this to my app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Framework" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="14.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```